# SBT: how to include both ordinary jar and test-jar of same dependency

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

In my SBT descriptor I have:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.neo4j" % "neo4j-kernel" % neo4jVersion,
  "org.neo4j" % "neo4j-kernel" % neo4jVersion % "test" classifier "tests" // test-jar
)
```

With this setup I don't get `test-jar` dependency (second line). But if I remove the first line, than `test-jar` dependency is in place.

How to include both dependencies?

Comment: i suspect the trick is in how you actually depend on the library elsewhere in your project definition. could you add more information? see also http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html#the-librarydependencies-key

Comment: I just add these two deps to `libraryDependencies` using `++=` operator as usual. However, the first one (without test) 'shadows' the second one independent of order they appear. I think they should somehow be combined into one.

Comment: i still think a little more context of the `libraryDependencies` code might illuminate things. e.g. it's something like `libraryDependencies ++= Seq(...)` where `...` has commas between the items?

Comment: This `"org.neo4j" % "neo4j-kernel" % neo4jVersion % "compile,test" classifier "tests"` works but makes test classes available in production code.

Comment: I believe this is [this bug](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2002).

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to get test-jar available for your main ("compile") code? Or for your test code?

As per http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#ivy-configurations , if you're trying to get the test config of something else available for your main code, you'll need something like `% "compile->test"` (*my* 'compile' uses *their* 'test').

e.g. if you wanted both in main,

```
"org.neo4j" % "neo4j-kernel" % neo4jVersion
"org.neo4j" % "neo4j-kernel" % neo4jVersion classifier "tests" % "compile->test"
```

or if you just want the latter in test, try shuffling the order of `classifier` and `% "test"` maybe?

```
"org.neo4j" % "neo4j-kernel" % neo4jVersion
"org.neo4j" % "neo4j-kernel" % neo4jVersion classifier "tests" % "test"
```

Do paste `show compile:dependencyClasspath` vs `show test:dependencyClasspath` (at the sbt prompt)

Comment: I need to add Neo4j kernel dependency to 'compile' scope, and its `test-jar` version to 'test' scope. What you propose (shuffle the order) does not compile.

Comment: hmpf. that's odd b/c i'd assume "saying what you want" (incl. the classifier) could be modified by "saying where you want it".